# Convert a for loop into a while loop to parse lines

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I wrote the following for loop to parse some lines into keys and values in a dict.  How can I convert it to a while loop?

```
for i in range(len(lines)):
    string = lines[i].rstrip("\n")
    for j in range (len(string)):
        if string[j] == ':':
            user[string[:j]] = string[j+1:]
```

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop  We are not a code translation service.

Comment: Instead of using `for i in range(len(lines)):` and referring only to `lines[i]`, you should be using `for line in lines:`. Converting this to a `while` loop would be less clear than the `for` loop (you would have to refer to the underlying iterator).

Answer (score 5):

You don't need most of the code you've written to accomplish splitting each line on `:` and storing the result in a dict.  Just use a for loop over the lines and `.split()`.

```
for line in lines:
    key, value = line.strip().split(':', 1)
    user[key] = value
```

This can be reduced to a comprehension.

```
user = dict(line.strip().split(':', 1) for line in lines)
```

---

If you really want to use a while loop, you could pop values from the list until it is empty.

```
while lines:
    key, value = lines.pop().strip().split(':', 1)
    user[key] = value
```

If you don't want to modify the list in place, make a copy first and work with the copy.

```
loop_lines = lines[:]
```